# Error in MATLAB's plot function

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I have this function

`h45 = @(x) 1 / (1 + exp(-thDesnorm' * [1 45 x]'));`

where thDesnorm is:

```
[-23.6608
   0.1919
   0.1866]
```

When i want to plot this function this way:

```
domain = 0:1:100;
figure;
plot(domain, h45(domain));
```

I get this error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in @(x)1/(1+exp(-thDesnorm'*[1,45,x]'))
```

**This function works when calling it with, for example, `h45(1)`.**

I guess than in plotting, the function is receiving all the domain vector as the parameter `x`, and not one by one the values of this vector.

Comment: The error message is explicit. `-thDesnorm'` does not have the same dimensions as `[1, 45, x]'`

Comment: Yes of course they have not same dimensions. `-thDesnorm'` is 1x3 and `[1 45 x]'` is 3x1`.

Comment: If those were actually the sizes then the multiplication would not fail...

Comment: The problem was that the parameter was the full array as pysolver has solved. It works perfectly now with his fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the parameter `x` is your full array `domain`. This obviously causes a dimensional error in the dot product `thDesnorm'*[1,45,x]`. A quick fix would be using `arrayfun` to evaluate `h45`. For instance:

```
thDesnorm = [-23.6608
               0.1919
               0.1866];
h45 = @(x) 1 / (1 + exp(-thDesnorm' * [1 45 x]'));

domain = 0:1:100;
figure;
plot(domain, arrayfun(@(x)h45(x),domain)) % See modification in h45 call
```

[image]